# Migrationg flutter projects from v1 to v2

Tags: flutter

Hi guys I recently upgraded flutter to 3.0.5 and android studio to chipmunk I went to load an old project in the emulator and recieved this message

━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

C:\Users\PCPERFECT\StudioProjects\Bingo\bingo\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding.

When I click the link to get the migration steps I get a 404 page not found can someone lead me to a usefull guide.

Thamks

Comment: Also where exactly would I be able to add the --ignore-deprecation flag

Answer (score 0):

To remove this problem just follow my steps:
Step1: Open Main Activity of Android (JAVA/Kotlin)
Replace the main activity with this line of code

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

Step 2: Open AndroidManifest.xml
Make these changes

replace this:-

```
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

and after that you might need to upgrade your compileSdkVersion 31,
then flutter clean, flutter pub Get, flutter Pub upgrade
RUN THE PROGRAM